# Pandas: insert many rows at a specific location

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, insert, rows

There are several existing questions similar to this, but the answers are difficult to understand and none of them seem to do quite what I want.

I have a dataframe with many rows and a single column, including a row with a placeholder value I want to replace:

```
old = pd.DataFrame(['A','B','placeholder','C','D'],index=[0,1,2,3,4])
```

I have a second dataframe in the same format, which I want to insert at the location of the placeholder:

```
new = pd.DataFrame(['E','F'],index=[0,1])
```

The end result should look like this:

```
     0
0    A
1    B
2    E
3    F
4    C
5    D
```

I can get the index of the placeholder row:

```
ind = old.index[old[0]=='placeholder']
```

Based on the other questions similar to this, I thought the following code should do what I want:

```
old.loc[ind] = new
```

But it doesn't, it just replaces the placeholder with a NaN.
I then tried changing the indices in the new dataframe to be in between the rows I want to replace:

```
new = pd.DataFrame(['E','F'],index=[2,2.5])
```

This does exactly what I want, but the problem is that I don't know how to automate the index assignment. The real dataframes I'm working with are huge and already have 0-based indices, so I need to change the original indices of `new` to be something like:

```
np.arange(ind, ind+1, 1/len(new))
```

But here I am stumped on two aspects:

1. How to convert `ind` (the index of the placeholder) to a format I can actually use? It's currently an `Int64Index`, so I can't use it for `np.arange()`, and `ind.astype(float)` didn't seem to do anything.
2. Once I have a list of new indices, how can I replace the existing indices in `new` with the new indices?

Or, is there a more efficient approach entirely?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indices in `old` are consecutive numbers, we can make some use of it.

The first step is to read (and save) the index of the placeholder row:

```
plhInd = old.index[old[0] == 'placeholder'].tolist()[0]
```

Then you can generate 2 dataframes: "before" part (`old_1`) and
"after" part (`old_2`):

```
old_1 = old[old.index < plhInd]
old_2 = old[old.index > plhInd]
```

Then, to get the result, use `append` with `ignore_index=True` (two chained calls):

```
result = old_1.append(new, ignore_index=True).append(old_2, ignore_index=True)
```

When you `print(result)` you get:

```
   0
0  A
1  B
2  E
3  F
4  C
5  D
```

No need to "regenerate" the index, because under `ignore_index=True`
the "following" indices are generated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the index of `new`, add it to `old` and then sort and reset the index.

```
import pandas as pd

idx = old.eq('placeholder').idxmax()[0]
new.index = idx + new.index/len(new)

pd.concat([old.drop(idx), new]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

#   0
#0  A
#1  B
#2  E
#3  F
#4  C
#5  D
```

Or split the `DataFrame` and concatenate the new part in the middle:

```
new = pd.DataFrame(['E','F'],index=[0,1])  # re-initialize

idx = old.eq('placeholder').idxmax()[0]
pd.concat([old.iloc[:idx], new, old.iloc[idx+1:]], ignore_index=True)

#   0
#0  A
#1  B
#2  E
#3  F
#4  C
#5  D
```